# MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 944ef754a755

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a test environment, using JUnit 5, where I start up MongoDB in a Docker container. This is done in the `@BeforeAll` function of my test suite. I have a test for connecting to MongoDB, writing and reading a document, and it works fine.

After I start up the Docker container, then I start my Node.js service in the same `@BeforeAll` code, and I pass the Mongo URI, such as `mongodb://localhost:55021`, via a file in the file system. I have verified that my Node.js service gets the URI correctly.

However, in my Node.js service, when I try to connect to MongoDB I get

```
Cannot connect to MongoDB at mongodb://localhost:55021

MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 944ef754a755
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/ekolotyluk/dev/crypto/customer-js/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:310:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at process.processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map { '944ef754a755:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'docker-rs',
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    maxElectionId: new ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001"),
    commonWireVersion: 8,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

**Is there some magical difference in MongoDB URIs between the Kotlin Client API and the Node.js API?** Do the Java/Kotlin Mongo drivers differ that much from the Node.js drivers?

My Node.js code looks something like

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb")
const mongoUri = getMongoUri()
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri)

async function mongoConnect() {
  try {
    await mongoClient.connect()

  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`Cannot connect to MongoDB at ${mongoUri}\n`)
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

It would be nice if the Node.js Mongo driver had better diagnostics. Is there a way to force the driver to provide better diagnostics?

I suspect this may be related to https://baraksaidoff.medium.com/fixing-mongoserverselectionerror-while-connecting-mongodb-with-node-js-213aaf0bf596

However, in my environment, I don't know how to access the MongoDB whitelist programmatically.

In my Node.js application the only IP Address known seems to be `192.168.0.25` but in my Kotlin code `127.0.0.1` is also know. I suspect that `127.0.0.1` is on the whitelist, but `192.168.0.25` is not... ?

Comment: Is there a member named `944ef754a755` in the replica set configuration?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. I am running MongoDB in a test environment via https://github.com/silaev/mongodb-replica-set but I am not an expert with it yet... the ID after `ENOTFOUND` changes each time I run the test.

Comment: Seems like that may be an automatically generated hostname.

Comment: When I start MongoDB manually in a Docker container, everything works fine. My guess is the way MongoDB is configured in the `testcontainers` implementation, its whitelist is too restrictive, so it will not accept a connection from a different process than it was started in.